# Subclass psycopg2 exception and re-raise a custom instance

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I'd like to be able to extend psycopg2.DatabaseError and perform the following handling:

- catch `psycopg2.DatabaseError` in my code
- check some attributes on it (for example, `exc.diag.message_hint`), and if it is equal to the value that I expect, raise my own custom subclass of psycopg2.DatabaseError keeping all attributes of the original exception on my new instance.

```py
class MyCustomException(psycopg2.DatabaseError):
    def additional_method(self):
        """ Perform aditional logic """
...

try:
    ... # call database
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as exc:
    if exc.diag.message_hint == 'my_expected_value':
        # raise MyCustomException keeping the info from the exc
    raise exc
```

This way I'd be able to perform some custom handling in my code later based on exception type.
For now, I've had no success with it. Even if I try to manually copy attributes to the new instance (or provide them on initialization), I don't get it to behave exactly as the original exception does (and this is what I'm aiming for): for example, even though I copy `diag` object from the original exception to the new instance, the new instance's `diag.sqlstate` is `None`.

Is this even possible? Are there unexpected drawbacks?